# How to add horizontal drop down submenu without overlapping, or hiding behind banner?

Tags: html, css

Under the "Internship Program" menu, I am trying to add "FAQ" and "Testimonials" as a horizontal drop down sub-menu however, since I am no expert in CSS, I can't seem to make the sub-menu work correctly.

Here is a link to the site: http://amchaminternship.org/testimonials.html

Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

```css
#menu {
  background: url(images/menu-tail.gif) repeat-x 0% 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 43px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 175px;
  right: 0;
}
#menu li a {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
#menu li:hover a {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0 29px 0 29px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #ffcc39;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="internship">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" id="logo" alt="">
    </a>
    <div id="menu">
      <p style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"></p>
      <div>
        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0pt;">
          <li><a href="index.html" id="index">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="internship_program.html">Internship
Program</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="alumni.html">Alumni</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="donations.html">Donations</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="who_we_are.html">Who We Are</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="info-box">
      <img src="images/sb_home.jpg" alt="Flags" height="297" width="234">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through your DOM and CSS is kinda challenging, so let me just answer with how *I* would do it and glean from it what you will:

```css
.menu { margin: 0; padding: 0; } /* reset your <ul>s */
    .menu-item {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative; /* relative so the submenu position will work */
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
        .menu-submenu {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;  /* reset your <ul>s */
            position: absolute;
            left: -9999em; top: -9999em; /* send it offscreen */
        }
        .menu-item:hover > .menu-submenu {
            left: auto; top: auto; /* bring it back onscreen on :hover */
        }
            .menu-submenu-item { display: block; }
    .menu:after { /* clearfix */
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="menu-submenu">
            <li class="menu-submenu-item"><a href="#">SubLink</a></li>
            <li class="menu-submenu-item"><a href="#">SubLink</a></li>
            <li class="menu-submenu-item"><a href="#">SubLink</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I used your example and made it work to a certain extent - the trouble I am having now is that the drop down submenu is pushing the flags image down. In addition, I also can't seem to get the {background:url(images/menu-divider.gif) no-repeat 0% 15px ...} in the .menu-item to look like it should on this link: http://amchaminternship.org/index.html. Hope I am making sense - thank you for your assistance thus far.

Comment: I finally got it to work by adding z-index, so now everything is working great. For the final touches, now I just need to figure out how to make my links change color when a mouse hovers over it :)

Comment: Awesome. So does this answer suffice to Accept it, or is there anything else I can clarify about it?

Comment: Actually, I do have another question. It is in regards to the horizontal menu divider. I can't seem to figure out the correct padding (if that is what it is), to space it like on this webpage: http://amchaminternship.org/faq.html. The webpage I am working on is http://amchaminternship.org/testimonials.html - let me know if I need to create a new question for it, or post it here with the html and CSS, thank you!

Comment: @nuntiavi yeah, go ahead and create a new question for that one. I meant is there anything specific to this question or my answer that I can clarify? If this sufficiently answered your question, you can Accept it. (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)